# Solution existence for "prime of primes"

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have the following problem:

Let there be a natural number $N$ and $N > 3$. Then I define a set of bounds:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
N &> P \\
P &> Q \\
P &= \sum_{i=0}^S q_iQ^{S-i} \\
Q &= \sum_{i=0}^S q_i \\
S &= \lfloor\log_QP\rfloor
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

Question would be: how many solutions does this have with the condition that $P, Q, q_0...q_s$ are primes?

Or more specific, is it possible to prove that for any natural number $N$ there is at least one number $P$ so that another prime number $Q$ exists which satisfies these conditions?

I wrote a simple program that tries the naive approach to check if there are such primes for a big number $N$ but it still is able to find relatively "big" solutions and it actually is able to find them for arbitrary big $N$. Also, it seems to "not work" for small $N$ - but I guess it's not that important on "infinite" scale (or else we could adjust initial $N>3$)

Example of what I found is $102241 = 19(73^2)+13(73^1)+41(73^0)$ so $P=102241,Q=73,q_0=19,q_1=13,q_2=41$

Comment: Are you sure you mean $N > P$ and not the other way around?

Comment: Observation: Schinzel's "Hypothesis H" conjectures that there are infinitely many primes $Q$ such that $Q-2$ and $Q^2-2Q+2$ are also prime. Then $P=(Q-2)Q+2$ satisfies your conditions. Proving anything, of course, is another matter....